Does Adobe Bridge 2024 support the HEIC format?
Does Adobe Bridge 2024 support the  HEIC format? I wasn't able to find that seemingly easy piece of information online. My photo collection contains HEIC images and I'd like to browse them without having to reencode them.

Yes it does, at least it does on a Mac.
